# emacs buffer display garbled

Tags: emacs, centos, editor

Recently, my emacs editor's behavior is very strange. I could not find cause. Maybe emacs's version, or some wrong configures?

***emacs version 24.5.1
OS: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)***

[image]
**helm projectile find files display strangely. when delete the file path, the cursor jump disorderly.**

[image]

**when edit, the characters are also out-of-order ~**

Comment: Running in a terminal or with a GUI?

Comment: Running in a terminal(using ssh to connect)